# How do I covert one singular string in a list to an integer

Tags: python, string, list, integer

Trying to convert 12hr clock to 24hr clock. Input = 11:00 PM, output should be 23:00.
I know I have to add 12 to it when it’s PM time but to do so I need to turn the number from a string to an integer.

```py
hr24 = list(input().split(“ “))
hr24[0] = int(hr24[0])
```

AND

```py
hr24 = list(input().split(“ “))
hr24[0] = map(int, hr24[0])
```

Both result in errors can anyone help?

Comment: Note that you have smart quotes in your `input.split` call instead of traditional double quotes. What is the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#module-datetime) module to parse the time and display it as you want:

```py
import datetime as dt

t = '11:00 PM'
d = dt.datetime.strptime(t, '%I:%M %p')
h24 = d.strftime('%H:%M')
print(h24)  # 23:00
```

See also [`strftime()` and `strptime()` Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

Answer (score 0):

```
# store input in a string    
input_str = input()
# split the input string at the space, store time and period 
time, period = input_str.split(' ')

res = input_str
if period == 'PM':
    # split time at ':', store hour and minutes
    hour, minutes = time.split(':')
    # convert hour to int add 12 and convert back to string
    res = str(int(hour) + 12) + ':' + minutes

print(res)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**